# Wordpress get custom post type label name

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I want to echo a custom post type lable/Menu_name.

Example:

I create custom post type named: Product

In product post type I add post Ice Cream.

So I want to echo in ice cream page this example link:

Home/product/Icecream

Basically its like breadcrumb for custom post type.

Comment: How about selecting an answer @Abdullah

Answer (score 25):

Get the [post_type object](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type_object) to get the labels' `singular_name` or plural `name`,

```
$post_type_obj = get_post_type_object( 'ice_cream' );
echo $post_type_obj->labels->singular_name; //Ice Cream.
echo $post_type_obj->labels->name; //Ice Creams.
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using wordpress custom post type, then you can get required info by following funcitons:

1. Custom post type label

   $post_type = get_post_type_object( get_post_type($post) );
   $post_type->label
2. Custom field title

   $field_name = "ice_cream";  //slug of custom field "Ice Cream" 
   $field = get_field_object($field_name);

so you can use them in your breadcrumb as: 
    $post_type->label / $field['label']

Answer (score 1):

you can use this in the loops

```
<?php echo get_post_type_object(get_post_type())->labels->singular_name; ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe the Breadcrumb NavXT Wordpress plugin has support for using custom post types in breadcrumb navigation:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/breadcrumb-navxt/

http://mtekk.us/code/breadcrumb-navxt/

Hopefully the plugin should help you resolve your issues.

Comment: I am using this plugin but its not showing the custom post type name.
It shows:

Home > Product Post Title

I want:

Home > Product (custom Post type) > Post title